# How to fetch value from inner object in mongo query result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongodb.

I have this object in my collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b549be38d9f1c00160117d3"),
    "name" : "Name of object",
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c" : 100
        }
    }
}
```

What interests me is the 100 value, I want to fetch it from the object.
When I query the collection like this:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({}, {'name':1, 'a.b.c':1})
```

I only get the same object with the inner objects.
Is there a way to query it so that I will get a result like this:

```
{"Name": "Name of object", "c":100}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [Mongo aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) query you can get the result. In [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage of Mongo aggregate query you can add the conditions as per requirement.

Please try this query, might you will get the result:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    "name": "$name",
    "c": "$a.b.c",
    _id: 0
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Mayuri, You can achieve this by using `.aggregate()` but if you wanted to look at difference between [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) in aggregation *(Vs)* projection in `.find()`, check out :

So one first thing with `$project` is it is much more powerful & can accept a lot more features that are helpful to transform the fields. But projection in `.find()` is pretty straight forward that can accept only few things : [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#projection) i.e; value to a field in projection can be one of these :

```
1 or true to include the field in the return documents.
0 or false to exclude the field.
Projection Operators : $, $elemMatch, $slice, $meta
```

**Actual Issue :**

In your query when you're doing `'a.b.c':1` in projection it means you're returning `c` field in the output, As field `c` is nested in `b` & `a` the output structure doesn't change & you'll be getting the `c` value under the same structure, but if you use aggregation `{ $project: { "c": "$a.b.c" } }` it means you're assigning value of `"$a.b.c"` to a field named `c`. **How ? :** So when `$` is used against a field in aggregation it will access field's value, which helps for assignment.